Find all columns with "dateformat" in dataframe
For the following df I would like to extract columns with "dates":
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["USD", 12.3, 1, 23.33, 33.1],["USD", 32.1, 2, 34.44, 23.1]],columns= ['currency', '1999-07-31', 'amount', '1999-10-31', '2000-01-31'])




currency
1999-07-31
amount
1999-10-31
2000-01-31




USD
12.3
1
23.33
33.1


USD
32.1
2
34.44
23.1



Current code:
datetime_types = ["datetime", "datetime64", "datetime64[ns]", "datetimetz"]
dates = df.columns.to_frame().select_dtypes(include=datetime_types)

Current output:
dates.to_string()

'Empty DataFrame\nColumns: []\nIndex: [currency, 1999-07-31, amount, 1999-10-31, 2000-01-31]'

Desired output:
[1999-07-31, 1999-10-31, 2000-01-31]


You can't use select_dtypes in this context, this function filters based on the dtypes of the columns, not their names.
You can however use pd.to_datetime with errors='coerce' and notna to form a boolean indexer:
out = df.loc[:, pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='mixed')
                  .notna()]

Output:
   1999-07-31  1999-10-31  2000-01-31
0        12.3       23.33        33.1
1        32.1       34.44        23.1

If you just want the column names:
cols = df.columns[pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce', format='mixed').notna()]

Output: Index(['1999-07-31', '1999-10-31', '2000-01-31'], dtype='object')

Perfect answer, as usual, thank you!
